# (Haskell) Syntax for chaining functions with bindings in do block

Tags: haskell

I have the following code that chains functions using a monad, binding the intermediate results.

```
r :: Int -> Maybe Int
r n = do
  r1 <- f1 n
  r2 <- f2 r1
  r3 <- f3 r2
  r4 <- f4 r3
  return r4
```

where the type signature of the f1-f4 is
`f1 :: Int -> Maybe Int`.

The code works, however I would like to avoid naming the intermediate results (r1-r4).

If I wasn't working with monads, I could simply write `r = f1 . f2 . f3 . f4`. Is something similar possible for monads?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`(.)` is composition for regular arrows (`a -> b`). `(>=>)` is composition for Kleisli arrows (`a -> m b`).

```
import Control.Monad

r :: Int -> Maybe Int
r = f1 >=> f2 >=> f3 >=> f4
```